# Ruby on Rails - Stripe - Heroku - no Stripe api_key provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, stripe-payments

```
 Pay::Stripe::Error (No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". 
 You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. 
 See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.)
```

Pretty sure I have added this api key to every possible place, probably I am blind or something. Stripe works without any errors on development, but keeps giving same error on production.

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
  Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :private_key)
end

if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
    :secret_key => ENV['PRIVATE_KEY']
  }

  Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.private_key
end
```

config/secrets.yml

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
  private_key: <%= ENV['PRIVATE_KEY'] %>
  public_key: <%= ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>
```

rails credentials:

```
stripe:
  public_key: pk_test_xxx
  private_key: sk_test_xxx
```

Using 2 spaces in rails credentials^

Here is config vars
[image]

Help me figure it out please, I literally spent a day trying to solve this

Comment: If i check `Rails.application.secrets.private_key` in heroku console, it gives right key. Somehow this line just doesn't work `Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.private_key`

Comment: You might need to change this line `Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.private_key`, to this `Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]`

Comment: @ellitt doesn't work, tried already

Comment: @ellitt calling for `Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]` in `heroku console` gives the right key. Looks like it just doesn't save under `Stripe.api_key`

Comment: If you've set up your env variables so that they're consistently named in every environment, then you shouldn't need to do any conditional checking like `if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?` or `if Rails.env.production?` in the initializer. If your env variable is called `ENV['PRIVATE_KEY']` in development, test, and production, then you can just avoid all the conditional checking and say `Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  secret_key: ENV['PRIVATE_KEY']
}` and then `Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]`

Comment: @ellitt even if i just put `Stripe.api_key = 'xxx'` in stripe.rb it still gives the same error, tf

Comment: Also if you haven't restarted your Heroku dynos since changing those config variables, do that.

Comment: @ellitt I get your point and totally agree with you, but it still doesn't work. How it is still not working even after i hard coded this api key? I have restarted dynos also. Maybe this happens because I use Pay gem for stripe?

Comment: It's certainly possible that the Pay gem has additional configuration or something similar. I'm not familiar with it so I can't help there.

Comment: @ellitt is it possible that my prod server just can't decode the credentials? I haven't added master key to heroku config vars

Comment: Certainly possible I suppose. You could check out these two articles: https://medium.com/@thorntonbrenden/rails-and-the-legendary-master-key-15c8be7799f1 https://dev.to/raaynaldo/the-power-of-rails-master-key-36fh

Comment: It worked perfectly after I ran `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<your-master-key-here>` Looks like heroku have to know ur master key in order to decrypt any credentials! Thanks for articles @ellitt